# Return robocopy console results using psexec as LocalSystem

Tags: powershell, cmd, psexec, robocopy, invoke-command

I am trying to invoke a PowerShell command that executes `psexec` on the remote machine as the Local System account that then executes `robocopy` (via `CMD /C`) in logging mode to enumerate all files and file sizes within specific local folders.

I cannot get any data back from the `robocopy` command, although if I use a simple echo command to generate some data, I receive the data back fine.

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computerName -ScriptBlock {
  psexec -s cmd /c "robocopy C:\Windows\Temp C:\Windows\Temp /e /l /ns /np /njh /BYTES"
}
```

I have to gauge all sizes and quantity of data from a very large number of file servers where permissions are FUBAR. A large permissions change would cause a huge deal of replication that our infrastructure can't handle.

Comment: I think you are having an issue as your are signing into a remote system to the run as a different user. I think it is referred to as the double hop issue. Why not just use `psexec` outright and skip `Invoke-Command`. `& psexec.exe \\$computerName -s cmd.....`

Comment: Why are you running `psexex` via `Invoke-Command`, why are you running `robocopy` in `cmd` when you don't use anything that would require `cmd`, and why are you trying to copy `C:\Windows\Temp` onto itself?

Comment: Thanks both, although I have already tried that. WAN speeds are terrible and the file count reaches into the millions in some cases. The command needs to be executed on the remote machine. What is strange is that I can see psexec and robocopy running on the remote system, and CPU sits high while it enumerates files, although all I get back on completion is the standard robocopy copyright message, and then a 0 exit code. It's like robocopy executes yet another process that isn't being written into the remote CMD console... maybe robocopy isn't the answer...

Comment: I have resolved this issue by using a custom written function "Invoke-TokenManipulation" which works really well: https://github.com/clymb3r/PowerShell/tree/master/Invoke-TokenManipulation

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/clymb3r/PowerShell/tree/master/Invoke-TokenManipulation

I used this function as opposed to using psexec.